# pass type to dependency injection container

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I am supporting multiple databases without using ORM tools. For this example I will show an example for Postgres and MSSQL *UserQueries*

[image]

I have an interface `IDataBase` with multiple databases implementing this interface.

```
@injectable()
export class MssqlDatabase implements IDatabase {
    public async connect(): Promise<void> {
    }

    public async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    }
}
```

Further I have my `IUserQueries` interface defining the queries

```
export interface IUserQueries {
    fetchUsers(): Promise<QueryResult>;
}
```

`QueryResult` is a custom class to make sure, every database query returns the same data object for my API. My API calls the specific query from the target interface. If `mssql` is the identifier in the config file, my application should create a connection to the MSSQL database. But my API files shouldn't care and don't know this (obviously, that's what a interface does).

A basic example would be

```
@injectable()
export class UserRepository implements IUserRepository {
    public userQueries: IUserQueries;

    constructor(@inject(IoCTypes.IUserQueries) userQueries: IUserQueries) {
        this.userQueries = userQueries;
    }
}
```

Now things get tricky here. My DI container:

```
const container: Container = new Container();
container.bind<IUserQueries>(IoCTypes.IUserQueries).to(/* what? */);
export { container };
```

The DI container doesn't know which query file to pick. It could be the `MSSQLUserQueries` or `PostgresUserQueries`. How can I solve this problem? It is possible to select the right queries when starting the server (**app.ts**) but as far as I understood, this DI container is completely independent from the application and just acts as a config file so I shouldn't pass in an abstract `UserQueries` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of factory pattern:

```
interface IUserQueryFactory {
    get(): IUserQueries;
    get(type: string): IUserQueries;
}

class UserQueryFactory implements IUserQueryFactory {
    get(): IUserQueries {
        const defaultValue = config.database; // or whatever returns your "mssql" from config
        return this.get(defaultValue);
    }

    get(type: string): IUserQueries {
        switch (type) {
            case "mssql":
                return new MSSQLUserQueries();
            case "postgresql":
                return new PostgresUserQueries();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

const container: Container = new Container();
container.bind<IUserQueryFactory>(IoCTypes.IUserQueryFactory).to(UserQueryFactory);
container.bind<IUserQueries>(IoCTypes.IUserQueries).toDynamicValue((context: interfaces.Context) => { return context.container.get<IUserQueryFactory>(IoCTypes.IUserQueryFactory).get(); });
export { container };
```

I'm not sure I've got the whole syntax correctly since this is not tested, but I guess you get the idea:

1. `IUserQueryFactory` returns `IUserQueries` based on input type or returns default one (one defined in configuration) if type is not provider
2. Default implementation for `IUserQueries` is basically implemented through `IUserQueryFactory` which means that whole source of creating `IUserQueries` is at single place and easily maintanable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is about selecting one of the concrete implementations (`MSSQLUserQueries`, `PostgresUserQueries`) of some interface (`IUserQueries`) at the runtime - based on some configuration. The simplest approach is to use a factory, which knows about the configuration and returns the correct implementation of `IUserQueries`.

```
container.bind<interfaces.Factory<IUserQueries>>(IoCTypes.IUserQueriesFactory).toFactory<IUserQueries>((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return () => {
        const config = context.container.get('configuration');
        //if config.isPostgresql return PostgresUserQueries
        //if config.isMssql return MSSQLUserQueries
    };
});
```